# Python numpy simulation strangely don't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have this code, but somehow it don't work like I want it. Basically I read in the .geno file, and from possib I read the percent that i want to keep from it, the others I want to be 9. The first round is perfect, but the second percent became wrong, like it commulate the numbers, but I read in the array every loop, so I don't understand why it won't work. In this link there is the .ind and .geno files for testing.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15VqGbVib41a4bDSVuPiqy_hkcCGK7H4H?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import process_time
import random
from argparse import ArgumentParser

ind = pd.read_csv("test_bckg100.ind", delimiter=r"\s+", header=None)
ind.columns = ['ID', 'Sex', 'Pop']
sample_size = [1] * len(ind)
sample_list = list(ind['ID'])
# make a list for all p values
possib = [0.95, 0.9, 0.85, 0.8, 0.75, 0.7, 0.65, 0.6, 0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05]

t1_start = process_time()
geno = pd.read_fwf("test_bckg100.geno", widths=sample_size, header=None, dtype=np.uint8)
geno_arr = geno.to_numpy(dtype=np.uint8)
# geno_arr[0,:] oszlopok
# geno_arr[:,0] sorok
for p in possib:
    random.seed(1)
    needed_nine = round(len(geno_arr[:, 0]) * (1 - p))
    geno_temp = geno.to_numpy(dtype=np.uint8)
    for b in range(0,len(sample_list)):
        index = np.random.choice(np.arange(geno_temp.shape[0]), needed_nine, replace=False)
        geno_temp[index,b] = 9
    test_geno_arr = geno_temp[:, 0]
    good_pos = np.where(test_geno_arr == 9)
    print(needed_nine)
    print(len(good_pos[0]))
    #with open("BACKGROUND" + "_1_" + str(int(p*100))+".geno", 'w') as fout:
    #np.savetxt(fout, geno_temp, delimiter="", fmt='%d')

t1_stop = process_time()
print("Finished genotype files: ", t1_stop - t1_start)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change

```
geno_temp = geno.to_numpy(dtype=np.uint8)
```

to

```
geno_temp = np.copy(geno_arr)
```